# how to know the value variable defined in pom.xml?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have some multi-module Maven project, I am looking through whole pom.xml. I am beginner for Maven project, so not have enough knowledge to understand it comprehensively. There is some variable defined in pom.xml,

```
<dependency>
<groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
<artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
<version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I searched whole properties defined in pom.xml cause those are that I know of which variable can be defined for pom.xml.
Does anybody know about how I can figure I what the 'project.groupId' is? Is there any files or environments I can search for?

Answer (score 2):

> I searched whole properties defined in pom.xml cause those are that I know of which variable can be defined for pom.xml. Does anybody know about how I can figure I what the 'project.groupId' is? Is there any files or environments I can search for?

If you would like to explore the various properties, you may find the output of `mvn help:expressions` instructive; it lists the various starting points of such property expressions, e.g., `${project}` (the current project’s POM) or `${settings}` (the user’s settings).

You can then use `mvn help:evaluate` to explore the values of these properties. For example, if you enter `${project}` on `evaluate`’s prompt, you will see an XML rendition of the `${project}` object. Within this XML element, you can select child elements by a dot-separated path. A property like `${project.build.finalName}` will evaluate to to the value of the `<project>` > `<build>` > `<finalName>` element.